# Automatic Assignment of New Users to Chatter Groups

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I am working on a pair of a Process Builder flow and a Flow that take newly-created users and assign them to Chatter groups. Currently we are only assigning new users to the "All Chatter Users" group, but will eventually expand the flow to assign dynamically based on permission set.

I am running into issues even getting the flows to work correctly, and would love to get some input.

My initial Process Builder flow fires any time a User is created, and proceeds as long as the user is Active and is assigned either a Chatter Only, Salesforce, or Salesforce Platform license. Because you can't fire a Process Builder flow on a new User immediately (it will throw an immediate Flow execution error), I have a scheduled action for "0 days after CreatedDate." The Flow is then invoked, passing the User ID to a memberID variable on the Flow.

When I create a new user after activating, the Process Builder flow throws an error, as does the Flow (indicating that the Flow is at least invoked). The errors are below:

---

### Process Builder Flow Error

```
Error element myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_SA1 (FlowActionCall).
An error occurred when executing a flow interview. 
This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.
We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.

Flow Details
Flow Name: New_Users_to_All_Chatter_Group
Type: Record Change Process
Version: 13
Status: Active

Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: New_Users_to_All_Chatter_Group-13_InterviewLabel
Current User: Luke Miller (0058000000BgJmW)
Start time: 1/12/2018 3:40 PM
Duration: 85 seconds

How the Interview Started
Luke Miller (0058000000BgJmW) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = null
myVariable_current = 005c0000004ORTyAAO
ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime}

Result
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "1/12/2018 3:40 PM"
DECISION: myPreWaitDecision_myWait_myRule_1
Executed this outcome: myPreWaitRule_myWait_myRule_1
Outcome conditions: 1 AND (2 OR 3 OR 4)
1. {!myVariable_current.IsActive} (true) Equals true
2. {!myVariable_current.User_License_Type__c} (Salesforce) Equals Chatter Only
3. {!myVariable_current.User_License_Type__c} (Salesforce) Equals Salesforce
4. {!myVariable_current.User_License_Type__c} (Salesforce) Equals Salesforce Platform
Logic: Advanced Logic (1 AND (2 OR 3 OR 4))

DECISION: myDecision
Executed this outcome: myRule_1
Outcome conditions: 1 AND (2 OR 3 OR 4)
1. {!myVariable_current.IsActive} (true) Equals true
2. {!myVariable_current.User_License_Type__c} (Salesforce) Equals Chatter Only
3. {!myVariable_current.User_License_Type__c} (Salesforce) Equals Salesforce
4. {!myVariable_current.User_License_Type__c} (Salesforce) Equals Salesforce Platform
Logic: Advanced Logic (1 AND (2 OR 3 OR 4))

WAIT: myWait_myRule_1
The waiting conditions for the following wait events were met.
Wait Event: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0
Waiting Conditions:
1. {!myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_postActionExecutionVariable} (false) Equals false
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

Event Type: Alarm: Relative Time
Object Type = User
Record ID = {!myVariable_current.Id} (005c0000004ORTyAAO)
Offset Unit = Hours
Offset Number = 0
Base Date/Time Field = CreatedDate

Result
Started waiting at 1/12/2018 3:40 PM.
The interview started waiting at 1/12/2018 3:40 PM.
The interview was resumed at 1/12/2018 3:41 PM by Luke Miller (0058000000BgJmW).
WAIT: myWait_myRule_1
Wait event myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0 occurred.
The following values from the event were assigned to flow variables.
None.

DECISION: myPostWaitDecision_myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0
Executed this outcome: myPostWaitRule_myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!myVariable_current.CreatedDate} (1/12/2018 3:40 PM) Is null false
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
AUTOMATIC_USER_ASSIGNMENT_TO_CHATTER_GROUPS (FLOWS): myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_SA1

Inputs:
memberID = {!myVariable_current.Id} (005c0000004ORTyAAO)
```

---

### Flow Error

```
Error element createMembership (FlowRecordCreate).

This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id. For details, see API Exceptions.

This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.
We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.

Flow Details
Flow Name: Automatic_User_Assignment_to_Chatter_Groups
Type: Autolaunched Flow
Version: 5
Status: Active

Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: Automatic User Assignment to Chatter Groups 1/12/2018 3:41 PM
Current User: Luke Miller (0058000000BgJmW)
Start time: 1/12/2018 3:41 PM
Duration: 1 seconds

How the Interview Started
Luke Miller (0058000000BgJmW) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
memberID = 005c0000004ORTyAAO
RECORD QUERY: getMemberInformation

Find one User record where:
Id Equals {!memberID} (005c0000004ORTyAAO)
Result
Successfully found record.
{!memberName} = OkLetsDoThis Again

FAST LOOKUP: Lookup_Chatter_Group
Find all CollaborationGroup records where:
Name Equals All Chatter Users
Assign those records to {!allChatterUsersGroupID}.
Save these field values in the variable: Id

Result
Successfully found records.
DECISION: errorIfNoCollaborationGroup
Executed this outcome: Collaboration_Group_Found
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!collaborationGroupID} (null) Does not equal 
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
RECORD CREATE: createMembership
Create one CollaborationGroupMember record where:
CollaborationGroupId = {!collaborationGroupID} (null)
MemberId = {!memberID} (005c0000004ORTyAAO) 

Result
Failed to create record. 
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id. For details, see API Exceptions.
```

---

I know this is a big error to wade through, but I feel at a loss as to why the Process Builder flow is throwing an error while still passing the memberID variable through, then the Flow is not creating a CollaborationGroupMember despite finding and setting the collaborationGroupID and having the memberID.

Any insight would be helpful!